# Create database and generate table with dotnet migration from created models

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm newer to EF core and I followed an Asp.net core tutorial on Youtube (Presented in French ) [Link of the tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVtIlyCv7tw&ab_channel=BENTECHPROTV), this tutorial helped me to create my first Asp.net core application (.NET 5) using MVC and repository design pattern.
Unfortunately, this course does not explain how to create the database and how to ensure the migration in EF core?

I've added models, controllers and views and I would like to generate the tables `Famille` and `Produits`

Is it possible to generate automatically the database and the tables with EF core?

[image]

Comment: Could you please give me the link to this documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first create a database manually.

after that create a dbContext and connect it to your database by using this [link](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core-dbcontext.aspx) and this [one](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/create-model-for-existing-database-in-ef-core.aspx)
then add your models context inside it

now go to package manager console inside visual studio
write this command `enable-migrations`
then write this command to add a migration class `add-migration {migrationName}`
, after creating migration write this command to update your migration code inside database
by using this command `update-database`

for a complete documentation visit [microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0)